# Having trouble making connection BTW eclipse and Android emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I have installed ADT-bundle for `windows-x86_64` from `[www.developer.android.com][1]` , I was able to create a emulator . 
I am trying to run my "Hello world" program through emulator but in the console window of eclipse , it is saying the Following Errors

```
.
. 
013-01-09 21:21:08 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 557
[2013-01-09 21:21:09 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 558
.
.
```

I have no clue why it is going like this . Could you please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: Did you try re-starting adb/eclipse/system :)

Comment: try to execute adb kill-server and adb start-server commands in command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Please try to Restart your Adb Connection, because sometimes adb gets disconnected.

click **Windows -> Open perspective** ->choose **other**-> then a New Pop Window Opens in that click **DDMS-> In the Window Devices(leften side of IDE )** and you will see restart adb option in View Menu which besides Screen Capture option.**

Refer the Screen Shot I have attached here

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sankar! I tried to restart DDMS , the page was empty and all of the options in the top bar were grayed out. I have this message in my console :[2013-01-10 15:11:54 - adb] ADB server didn't ACK
[2013-01-10 15:11:54 - adb] * failed to start daemon *  thanks ...